# Hive words starting with a vowel

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table tbl_2016 with columns col1 and col2. I want to obtain the sum of col1 where col2 starts with a vowel.
I have tried the following code but I am afraid that Hive understands it as starting with “AEIOU” and not “A” or “E” or “I” or “O” or “U”:

```
select SUM(col1) as Total_col1 from tbl_2016 WHERE col2 LIKE "[AEIOU]%";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `RLIKE` to match regex:

```
select SUM(col1) as Total_col1 from tbl_2016 WHERE col2 RLIKE '^[AEIOU]';
```